# How to get a large collection of quantum circuits that are valuable to practitioners?

Tags: circuit-construction

I want to get a large collection of quantum circuits that matter to practitioners in quantum computing. I want a get many complete quantum circuits. For example, 1 million QASM files.
However, I could not readily find a large dataset.
Are there any places I could find it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to QCSE!  What do you mean by "a large collection of quantum circuits?"  Are you wondering how quantum gates are actually implemented?  Are you looking for a set of "standard cells" for quantum circuits that implement specific functions?  Are you familiar with [quantum gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate)?  Your goal is not clear right now with the way the question is framed.  I recommend you revise your question for clarity, and what you mean by "collection of quantum circuits."

Comment: @MarkS I am familiar with quantum gates. I am not specifically looking for standard cells, however if there was a method to generate many useful quantum circuits that happened to use standard cells that method would be very useful.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is your ultimate goal what to do with "1 milion QASM files"? It would help to answer your question.

Comment: I want to study how to reduce noise in quantum circuits that are valuable to practitioners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03719. You can find there information on algorithms and how to deal with noise and errors in quantum circuits. Moreover, it can help you to "generate bunch of QASM files" implementing algorithms presented there.